# Message tree list

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a nice task, and not sure which is the optimized version here. This is single threaded environment.

In Thunderbird, you can see the messages as tree. It will be a list of trees. Clicking on the tree elements you can navigate from root to leaf and back, probably has other mail clients, but I am not using others. Similar is the task here: display a message list in a tree view.

```
Message1
  Message1.1
  Message1.2
     Message1.2.1
Message2
Message3
   Message 3.1
```

And so on... I have a `Vector<Message> myMessages`

And a Message simplified POJO would be like this:

```
class Message{
      int id;
      int parentID;
      String topic;
      String content;
}
```

My question it is simple: what data structure should be used to store that tree? 
A LinkedHashMap with the key of those mesageid's which hs the parentID = null ( first message in topic) and the value should be an ArrayList which has all the messages? - or a nested LinkedHashMap?

How to store the Message 1.2.1 to easy know who is his parent?

Update: it will be listed in GWT / html, not Swing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered [JTrees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data) and the underlying [TreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) ? It's not clear to me if you're looking to *display* your data but regardless I would try and leverage off this work since it's feature-rich and looks like a natural fit for your problem.

Update: As you're using GWT, check out the [GWT Tree](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~Tree)

Comment: - as update I will not use exactly the tree but a tree model need here, not need to reinvent the wheel, problem solved

Answer (score 1):

¿Have you considered using JAXB? You can have an XSD with the structure you want for your message, that will generate a java class, for example: MessageType
Then you can create an array for your messages and you can get the sub-attributes from the getter methods.

Comment: +1, thanks, but I have already the list of the data from database